# How can I set up Selenium to use multiple Firefox profiles?

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium and want to use separate firefox profiles for 3 different scripts. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how you are executing your scripts, but when you instantiate your `webdriver` object, you can specify a `FirefoxProfile` as the `firefox_profile` argument. This is done by creating a `FirefoxProfile` object (example below) and providing the path to your target profile as the argument:

```
from selenium import webdriver
# ...
profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile('/path/to/your/profile')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

To the best of my knowledge you can't modify the profile after the `driver` has been instantiated (I could be wrong about this though - worth experimenting if that is what you need to do :) ). That being the case, in each of your scripts you would create a profile that pointed to the profile you want to use, and then instantiate the `driver` with the `firefox_profile` argument pointed to the `profile` object created by `FirefoxProfile`.