# How to switch Firefox profile with Selenium - without instantiating a new driver?

Tags: python, unit-testing, firefox, browser, selenium

Trying to find a way to switch the active profile in a Selenium Firefox driver.  [This question about multiple Firefox profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13868589/1663942) states that creating and using multiple profiles is possible.  However, it would be better if there were some way to switch the active Firefox profile within the driver session - instead of starting a new one.

How can I switch the active Firefox profile with Selenium?

Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't.  The profile controls lots of things about startup and running of a Firefox instance, so it wouldn't really make sense (if it were even technically possible) to be able to hot swap from one profile to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  Selenium does not let you change Firefox profiles, and I'm pretty sure even Firefox doesn't.