# multiple download folders using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the Selenium webdriver (in Python) to automate the donwloading of thousands of files. I want the files to be saved in different folders. The following code works, but it requires quitting and re-starting the webdriver multiple times, which slows down the process:

```
some_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"] # over 300 items on the actual code
for item in some_list:
    download_folder = "/Users/myusername/Desktop/" + item
    os.makedirs(download_folder)
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_folder)
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain")
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = fp)

    # a bunch of code that accesses the site and downloads the files

    browser.close()
    browser.quit()
```

So, at every iteration I have to quit the webdriver and re-start it, which is pretty innefficient. Is there a better way to do this? Apparently we can't change the Firefox profile after the webdriver is instantiated (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406271/how-to-switch-firefox-profile-with-selenium-without-instantiating-a-new-driver) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868589/how-can-i-set-up-selenium-to-use-multiple-firefox-profiles) previous questions), but perhaps there is some alternative I'm missing?

(Mac OS X 10.6.8, Python 2.7.5, Selenium 2.2.0)

Comment: Would it work to move the files using plain old Java?

Comment: Hhmm, I haven't tried it -- I'm a newbie to programming and I only know some Python.

Comment: I download all files to specified location and between each downloads I use rename method from os module to move and rename files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think you can do it.

**Option one: specify different default directories for one FirefoxProfile**

You can't. In my opinion, this is the issue with Firefox, not Selenium. However, this Firefox limitation looks like the correct design to me. **`browser.download.dir`** is the default download destination, if it allows multiple directories, then that's not **"default"** anymore.

**Option two: switch multiple FirefoxProfile for one driver instance**

If not doing it in Firefox, can FirefoxProfile be switched for same driver instance? As far as I know, the answer is no. (You have already done some research on this)

**Option three: use normal non-Selenium way to do the downloading**

If you want to avoid using this auto-downloading approach and do it the normal way (like Auto-it etc.), then it falls in the category of ["How To Download Files With Selenium And Why You Shouldn’t"](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/). But in this case, your code can be simplified.

```
some_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"] # over 300 items on the actual code
for item in some_list:
    download_folder = "/Users/myusername/Desktop/" + item
    some_way_magically_do_the_downloading(download_folder)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and learn some java and then see if I can understand the code in "How to Download..." and how I might translate it to Python.