# How to use Selenium via Python on Chrome to change multiple downloaded file directories without having to launch the web driver & link more than once?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to selenium and have been trying to do this for a while, and the only thing I can find online are methods that only change the download file directory at launch of the web driver and link. What I'm basically trying to do is download multiple files from one chrome page and have selenium change the download path directory for each one without having to relaunch the driver and browser every single time. Would appreciate any help or suggestions provided

Comment: Can you not just download all files in the same directory and then just move them elsewhere using `os.rename()`?

Comment: The file names are variable and change based on the date and time of download, so I was just wondering if selenium had a magic trick that would make my life a bit easier

Comment: I don't think it has a magic trick, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115633/multiple-download-folders-using-selenium-webdriver).

Comment: hmm my situation seems a bit grim. Any idea on how I could make my code locate file names that are based on date and exact time of download using os.rename()? Again really appreciate the help

Comment: You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to get the filenames and `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(filename))` to get the downloaded time (note on Linux this would be a bit different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `driver.command_executor` method to achieve this. It allows you to interact with the current browser session.
You can use this method to change the download path, without relaunching the web driver.

The code snippet is given below-

You can change the `'downloadPath'` parameter as per your requirement.

```
#initially setting the download path to current directory
driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow','downloadPath':os.getcwd()}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)

#your code to download the file

#followed by changing the download directory
#for example here I'm changing it to data folder inside the current working directory

driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow','downloadPath':os.getcwd()+'\data'}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

Comment: I tried this code and I am getting attachments downloaded with error. Can you tell me what's wrong

Comment: It'll be useful if you can share your problem in detail.