# Dynamic change of Selenium download path

Tags: python, selenium

I've an instance of Selenium webdriver with a defined default download path (the prompt is disabled because I've to download a lot of files).

I would like to let the user choose its own download path with a dialog box before starting to download but AFTER having created the Selenium instance.

Is is possible to change this path once the object has been created ?

Comment: Not possible I think.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I have answered a similar question, you can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68650389/how-to-use-selenium-via-python-on-chrome-to-change-multiple-downloaded-file-dire/69061132#69061132).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the add_experimental_option method to work in my environment but found a workaround using Chrome Development Protocol as demonstrated below.

```
# Initialise Driver 
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(<your options>)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)

# Set CDP setting
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
   "behavior": "allow",
   "downloadPath": <downloadPath>
})

# Trigger the download
driver.<find download button>.click()

# Set CDP setting
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
   "behavior": "allow",
   "downloadPath": <secondDownloadPath>
})

# Trigger the next download
driver.<find download button>.click()
```

Relevant Docs:
[CDP Docs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-setDownloadBehavior)
[Selenium Docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/)

One small caveat is that files seem to be overwritten instead of renamed with an appendix if the same file name is saved.

Answer (score -1):

For this to work, you need to use the absolute path. Here-

Assuming 'filename' as variable.

```
download_folder = r'C:\\Temp\\'+filename;

options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": os.path.abspath(download_folder),
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
```

Mind the indentations:)