# How to change the download path of a selenium docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium

I have a selenium docker on a UNRAID server, I tried to change the download path like this

```py
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
                    "download.default_directory": config.path,
                    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
                    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
                    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
                })
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-popup-blocking')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-browser-side-navigation')
driver = webdriver.Remote
             command_executor="http://IP:4444"
             options=chrome_options
          )
```

Unfortunately, nothing changes, the download directory is the default directory.
Did I make something wrong?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68650389/how-to-use-selenium-via-python-on-chrome-to-change-multiple-downloaded-file-dire/69061132#69061132) answer help?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It works on the host machine. The minute I try this on the container, I'm stuck.