# python selenium import my regular firefox profile ( add-ons)

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I've been trying to get my add-ons to work with my driver(driver as in webdriver.Firefox(profile)). I have no idea how to import (or if its optional at all) my regular Firefox profile. The one, i assume, contains all my add-ons.

Help is needed indeed.

Beside a solution (if available) an explanation to why my add-ons do not exist on the selenium webdriver could be a nice touch.

Thank very much!!

Comment: Did you see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868589/how-can-i-set-up-selenium-to-use-multiple-firefox-profiles

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do this, and set `path_to_my_profile` to where your usual profile resided, then Selenium should use your profile:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile

profile = FirefoxProfile(path_to_my_profile)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

I've not done this myself but I say this based on having read the code of Selenium. The reason Selenium does not use your profile by default is that by default a `FirefoxProfile` object is created with `None` as the first argument, which means "create a new profile for the Firefox instance we're about to launch".

By the way, what Selenium does by default (creating a new profile) is the best practice to ensure the repeatability of tests. It is a good thing.

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm :) and after working with it a bit, it seems to be better to work with a blank profile as you said.