# How to use Firefox profiles in Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am playing around with Firefox profiles.
I tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/<user name>/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/abc3defghij2.ProfileName')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get("https://www.example.com/membersarea")
```

As well as

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile

profile = FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/Bain3/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/g4sh4k5c.fa')
driver = webdriver.Firefox('C:/Users/Bain3/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/g4sh4k5c.fa')
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289598/python-selenium-import-my-regular-firefox-profile-add-ons")
```

This worked.  I then tried to launch it again and now firefox tends to not load any urls.  It seems that now when I use

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
```

This does loads the browser but not the url.
I think for some reason adding profiles seems to change the directory of geckodriver.  I am using python 3 Anaconda in a virtual env.  Changing the system directory, launching geckodriver and  Anaconda gecko-driver reinstall do not remedy this.
I thought perhaps changing  `driver = webdriver. Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Bain3\Music\geckodriver.exe')(fp)` 
might help.

Why could I only launch Firefox in a separate profile once and now it simply launches a blank firefox.  No error commands in console it's like it's frozen.

Here's an image of Firefox launching.. https://ibb.co/nwnkp5

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp,firefox_binary=binary)
```

the Argument needs to be: firefox_profile=fp

The binary option can be used to point to different installations/versions of installed Firefox